# Customize chapters in table of contents from "1", "2", ... to "Chapter 1:", "Chapter 2:", ... using \@starttoc

Tags: table-of-contents, token-lists

I need to use [this](https://github.com/skulumani/thesis-gwu) template for my thesis and having troubles modifying the labeling of chapters/sections in the table of contents. The way it is implemented right now is:

"1 blah

1.1 blah-blah

1.2 blah-blah"

I need it to be

"Chapter 1: blah

Section 1.1: blah-blah

Section 1.2: blah-blah"

I also need to do similar kind of formatting to List of Figures and List of Tables.

I assume it is somewhere inside the package itself where it has to be changed, since I can't see anything relevant in the provided code itself.

Just to save you a bit of time, the relevant code is in "thesis-gwu.cls".

---

Ok, the package is titlesec. And the helpful post is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411316/format-fonts-for-toc-lof-lot-with-tocloft). The code in the answer provides the way to customize the table of contents using titletoc package. Thanks to the community for helpful responses. The problem is resolved.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You tell people to use `\@starttoc`, but it has nothing to do with what you want. Also, why the tag `token-lists`?

Comment: If the University formatting guidelines have changed by now, please raise an issue on the github template page.

Comment: @Johannes_B This was my best guess. I assume, you have a better guess on how to change it. Would you like to share? If you don't know, I understand. I am the same way.